# Is it possible to make pointfree functions more readable using different combinators than (.)?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

What are potential alternative representations (e.g. using arrows, lenses, Haskell idioms, do syntax) of pointfree expressions that could read more like plain English?

Here is trivial example:

```
qNameIs :: String -> QName -> Bool
qNameIs = (. qName) . (==)
```

`QName` is a record from `Text.Xml`

What are possible equivalent to `qNameIs` but not pointful expressions? Ideally, ones that would show that first argument will be passed to `(==)` and result will be evaluated with result of `qName` applied to second argument of this expression?

Comment: I frequently replace `.` with `>>>`, because left-to-right order seems to have a more natural feel to it - I guess because it follows the order we're used to with english, and it's the typical way we make pipelines in other languages.

Comment: See also [semantic editor combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators).

Comment: `(==) <*> qName` is what you have.

Answer (score 8):

You can take the [.^](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointless-fun-1.1.0.5/docs/Data-Function-Pointless.html#v%3a.-94-) operator of the module [Data.Function.Pointless](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointless-fun-1.1.0.5/docs/Data-Function-Pointless.html):

```
import Data.Function.Pointless (.^)

qNameIs :: String -> QName -> Bool
qNameIs = (==) .^ qName
```

An example with arrows (its not elegant...):

```
qNameIs :: String -> QName -> Bool
qNameIs = curry $ uncurry (==) . second qName
```

You can also write a new operator:

```
with :: (a -> c -> d) -> (b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
with f g = (. g) . f
```

Then you can write:

```
qNameIs = (==) `with` qName
```

which can be read as "equal with qName" (you can also take another operator name).

In General you shall also have a look on the module [Data.Composition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Composition.html) (Unfortunately it does not help in your case...).

Comment: Maybe this shows better how the arguments apply, but it doesn't really read any "more like plain English."

Comment: Yeah, you are right... I also have to check my answer first, I think its not right...

Comment: Weak suggestion: `flip $ (==) . qName` - not like English, but somewhat more transparent than a `(.)` section.